# How can I go about Implementing Database transactions for SQL Server CE in a C#.Net Web-Pages w/ WebMatrix Environment?

Tags: c#, transactions, sql-server-ce, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

It has just come to my knowledge two important things considering the database I have that serves up web-page content, while simultaneously allowing a select few users to edit said pages.

1. Database transactions are required.
2. Database transactions might be incredibly complicated (from my C#.NET Web-Pages w/ WebMatrix environment's perspective).

So, I Wikipedia'd, Google'd, and even SO'd for even a small ray of hope on how to go about understanding how to simply get started with this, so that my database may be consistent.

After reading up on this topic (including this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172400.aspx), I have come to realize that while I am learning a bit more on transactions, I feel NO closer to actually implementing them myself, for my own SQL Server CE database.

I realize (at least somewhat) the magnitude of what I'm asking but was hoping someone who understands my environment (C#.NET Web-Pages w/ WebMatrix, using SQL Server CE) could perhaps provide an example of how this might be accomplished.

I don't need a whole lot of fancy stuff or anything, I just want to make sure that no one hits the database while saved changes are being committed (well, what I think I mean to say is that I want the users to receive the intended content, not crash the database if two users save at the same time, etc.).

Let's say I have a single table [testTable] with two columns [objectID, value].

I have a simple select statement [say: "SELECT * FROM testTable"] then I populate a page with it, whenever anyone visits it.

Now, say I have another page that a select few users can modify the viewable page with, then when they click "Save" it saves over the older values with something like ["UPDATE testTable SET objectID = @0, value = @1"]

Considering that I don't know how to begin the syntax for either the ADO.NET method, nor the straight SQL method, which is easiest considering my environment and what would the syntax be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not one that transactions solve. Transactions act as a wrapper around a number of operations, which either all succeed or all fail when you attempt to commit them. The problem you are trying to solve is one of concurrency. You just need to decide on a concurrency strategy. "Last in wins" is usually good enough for most CRUD systems - there is normally only one version of the truth, but your situation may require a different approach.

Other strategies are Optimistic Concurrency and Pessimistic concurrency:

*From this page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs6hb8k4(v=vs.80).aspx)*

> **Types of Concurrency Control**
>
> In general, there are three common ways to manage concurrency in a
>   database:
>
> - Pessimistic concurrency control: A row is unavailable to users from    the time the record is fetched until it is updated in the database.
> - Optimistic concurrency control: A row is unavailable to other users    only while the data is actually being updated. The update examines
>     the row in the database and determines whether any changes have been
>     made. Attempting to update a record that has already been changed
>     results in a concurrency violation.
> - "Last in wins": A row is unavailable to other users only while the    data is actually being updated. However, no effort is made to compare 
>     updates against the original record; the record is simply written 
>     out, potentially overwriting any changes made by other users since
>     you last refreshed the records.

Comment: As massive of a topic as database transactions are, I am very glad to hear that I was barking up the wrong tree. However, I (as I usually do) have a follow up question pertaining to your answer. How would my code reflect concurrency control? I feel pretty comfortable with the "Last in wins" strategy, as that seems to make the most sense to me here, but I am not sure the approach I should take from here. How would I go about making a "row unavailable to other users only while the data is actually being updated?"

Comment: Actually, I am reading the site you linked to now, so maybe that will reveal the answers my questions.

Comment: You don't have to do anything. The database will lock the row for the nanosecond that it takes to update values - if it needs to be locked at all.

Comment: I just got through reading the page you linked and it was very informative. Thank you for that. So it seems that I don't have to do anything at all. I guess I wasted a little time over-worrying here, but I would rather do that now, than find out I neglected some strategy that makes the site look bad later. I was really hoping you would see this question of mine in particular, as no one else seems to really understand this environment like you do. Thanks, Mike.

Comment: Hey, Mike, I have just 2 follow up questions, but I'll try to keep it simple. **1)**I have multiple tables that will need multiple rows to be added with INSERT sometimes and UPDATE other times, depending on the logic computed during the process of adding these rows. In short, in one single "Save" button click, could result in over 100 or even more separate `db.Execute` statements. Is a simple "Last-in-wins" structure still appropriate? **2)**If not, would it be practical to add a simple AppState variable to the `_AppStart` file that sets it to false, then turns true in the save file once...

Comment: ...saving has started, then back to false once it is done, while making sure that a "save" can only take place while this AppState variable is false? Does that make any sense?

Comment: I can't tell you which approach is best for your application. I know nothing about its rules. You should have enough information to be able to make an informed decision yourself by now, but I still think you are confusing concurrency and transactions.

Comment: I agree that that is a possibility, but for the sake of the 2 questions I just asked, I *think* I was only talking about concurrency here, but.... Anyway, how about if I just ask this: Using the AppState variable the way that I mentioned, would that seem like a normal solution if I just wanted to lock out anyone else saving while a save was in progress? I can handle how to inform the user of what's going on, of course, but I guess I just want to make sure that I don't have how the AppState variable works all wrong in my head.

Comment: You don't need to lock anyone out. The save takes a fraction of a nanosecond. If you want people to see that a record has been changed by someone else in real time, use SignalR.

Comment: The only thing I'm afraid of is that there could be only a few INSERT/UPDATE statements or possibly hundreds (depending on how much the user is saving). I had to do it this way to preserve the logic I needed to intelligently UPDATE or INSERT depending on existing or nonexisting IDs (in order to reuse them, if applicable) and the updates to relational tables. So instead of taking a fraction of a nanosecond, I think I am taking up to hundreds of fractions of nanoseconds, instead. I KNOW you know this environment well, so if you tell me I still shouldn't worry about, I won't worry about it.